Excel: how to ensure cells contain a comma separated list of specifically formatted values
I'm trying and failing to write a custom data validation for Excel such that cells can only contain a comma separated list of values, where each value consists of two capital letters followed by eight digits. A nice-to-have is that the comma separated values should be unique.
Ideally this would work in the Web-based version of Excel, but that might be pushing it.
I can validate a single value for the pattern AB12345678 straightforwardly...
=AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(CONCAT((FIND(MID(A1,1,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")),(FIND(MID(A1,2,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,3,8))),LEN(A1)=10)
...but can't work out how to apply this to multiple values in a comma separated list.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks all!

Apparently, there would be a RegexTest() function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/regextest-function-7d38200b-5e5c-4196-b4e6-9bff73afbd31

It's good to share expected output of the formula. Should the result only contain unique values, or the input as well? (So in case of duplicate values meeting the condition, list only one, or consider it invalid?

Also, if a cell contains a mix of correct and false values, would you want to list the correct ones only, or none?

Using BYCOL() and TEXTSPLIT() (and AND()):
No AND():
=BYCOL(TEXTSPLIT(A7,","),
LAMBDA(a,    
AND(
ISNUMBER(VALUE(CONCAT((FIND(MID(a,1,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")),(FIND(MID(a,2,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))))),
ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(a,3,8))),
LEN(a)=10)))

With AND():
=AND(
BYCOL(TEXTSPLIT(A7,","),
LAMBDA(a,    
AND(
ISNUMBER(VALUE(CONCAT((FIND(MID(a,1,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")),(FIND(MID(a,2,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))))),
ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(a,3,8))),
LEN(a)=10))))

This will output an array, if you wrap an AND() around it, it will output just TRUE or FALSE.

Note, I TEXTJOIN()-ed the list from A1:A5 in cell A7, with ", ".

Sample 2 to show FALSE output.
(Excel in different language, WAAR = TRUE, ONWAAR = FALSE)
Also note: this doesn't exclude duplicates:

Cell highlight manually done

just to note that I managed to do this following a suggestion (thank you!) to use textsplit():
=AND(ISNUMBER(VALUE(FIND(MID(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",",,TRUE),1,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",1))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(FIND(MID(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",",,TRUE),2,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",1))),ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",",,TRUE),3,8))),LEN(TEXTSPLIT(A1,",",,TRUE))=10)

Posting this in case it's useful to anyone else. If the "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" makes this formula too long for custom data validation (255 character limit) put that in a cell and refer to it in the formula. Note this doesn't enforce uniqueness, that's been a step too far for me thus far!
